# Android Recycler View with Multiple ViewHolders, Drag and Drop, and Persistent Item Positions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, android-viewholder

I'm working on an Android app where I need to implement a RecyclerView with multiple ViewHolders. These ViewHolders represent different types of items with varying layouts. Additionally, I want to allow users to drag and drop these items within the RecyclerView and have their positions saved for the next time the app is opened.

I've researched various tutorials and libraries, but I'm still struggling to piece everything together. Could someone provide guidance on how to achieve this functionality effectively? Specifically, I'm looking for advice on setting up the RecyclerView with multiple ViewHolders, implementing drag and drop functionality, and persistently saving the item positions.

Thank you in advance for any insights or code examples you can provide!

I've explored various solutions, including adjusting the layout parameters and using different drag-and-drop libraries, but I'm still facing this problem. My goal is to have the dragged item maintain its original size throughout the drag operation.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or could offer insights into what might be causing this behavior? If possible, I'd appreciate any code snippets or suggestions to resolve this size-changing problem during drag-and-drop operations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.